# Read files on remote Windows machine using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, windows, ssh, paramiko

I need to read and process a file on a remote Windows machine from Linux. I can setup the SSH session and run some simple command with Python Paramiko, but I couldn't figure out the way to read a remote file.  The remote file is a log and I'm expecting to read and process some lines in each execution of a loop. Appreciate if somebody can share your ideas or codes.

Answer (score 0):

For manipulating remote files over an SSH connection, do not use shell commands, use the standard SSH file management API, the [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol).

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
# ...
ssh.connect(...)

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

with sftp.open("/remote/path/my.log", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # process the line as you need
        print(line.rstrip())
```